# Extracting Numbers from String in C

Tags: c, string

I have an ASCII string coming from UART that looks something like "43.533a,5532" and I'd like to extract the two numbers. My idea was to separate them using strtok with the comma as delimiter and then remove the last character from the first string and afterwards convert the numbers using atoi() or is there an easier way with sscanf()? String manipulation is nothing I'm regularly using.
Another problem is, if the String looks different, how could I catch that beforehand?

Comment: You want to extract two numbers separating by comma?

Comment: Is it always `a,` that separates the two numbers? Or can it be a different letter? Can it be multiple letters?

Comment: @user3386109 if it will not, this is what he is asking

Comment: idk but best bet is to use loop indexing from 0 to len(string) and use if statement for finding if it is ascii(48-57) and store the result in an array

Comment: it's "always" 'a,' that separates the two numbers... but the string could also look completely different, then I just have to recognize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do this easily with `sscanf()`.

Following is an example. See it [working here](https://ideone.com/gA2PKY):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float a;
    int b;
    char *sNum = "43.533a,5532";

    sscanf(sNum, "%fa,%d", &a, &b);
    printf("a= %f || b= %d", a,b);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
a= 43.533001 || b= 5532
```

*Note:* Since float is having precision to `6` decimal place by default, so you may need to consider it and correct it if necessary.

Comment: Why didn't I see this... shame on me! Was alreading thinking of regex

Comment: Sorry one question,... what would happen in this case if the input string would be "ewwf22"? Would I have to catch that before the sscan()?

Comment: @Humpawumpa Yes, Because in above example _formatting string_ is static. So it cannot fetch numeric part from input `ewwf22`. It will be problematic. You need to use another `sscanf()` for this.

Comment: @Humpawumpa `sscanf("%*[^0123456789]%d", &b)` might suffice.